# WCF service listening to Windows Server Service Bus (WSSB) 1.1 on a queue

Tags: wcf, queue, listener, servicebus

I am trying to design a WCF service that would listen to WSSB 1.1 queue. Pl find the service contract and config below.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    [ReceiveContextEnabled(ManualControl = true)]
    void ReceiveDocument(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg);
} 

 public class Service : IService
{
    public void ReceiveDocument(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Message reached queue");
    }
}

<services>
      <service name="MyNameSpace.Service">
        <endpoint name="DocumentReceived" address="sb://<mycomputername>/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace/queue" binding="netMessagingBinding" bindingConfiguration="messagingBinding" contract="MyNameSpace.IService" behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

After deployment, I am browsing the service wsdl manually to make sure it is warmed up. Still It is not working when I post a message to the WSSB queue. It should print diagnostics messages in Dbgview. Is there any issue with the above code ? Am I missing anything here ? Pl help.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not connecting to the SB. If it is being tested on a Windows 7 machine instead of Server machine, it can give issues with Token provider service (STS). Hence for testing in Windows 7, use Shared access signature instead of Windows STS uri. Add WCF tracing to the service for more information.